# How to save the checkedmultiple boxes values

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following datatable which shows the checkboxes dyamically and the record with those check boxes.
Now i want to get the values of selected boxes and want to pass those value to other webService.
Following in the picture the questions and their data is dynamic.
[image]

```
                <p:row styleClass="ui-panelgrid-cell" rowspan="3">
                    <p:column>
                        <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">                              
                            <p:dataTable var="tQuestions"
                                value="#{userPreferences.availableQuestions}"
                                emptyMessage="No Questions Found." id="sTable">
                                <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText id="sName" styleClass="cellLabelMand"
                                         value="#{tQuestions.shortText}" />
                                <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />                                              
                                        <ui:repeat var="tCategoryList" value="#{tQuestions.categoryList}">
                                        <p:selectOneRadio id ="userChoice" value="checked"  />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{tCategoryList.categoryValue}" />
                                        </ui:repeat>                                                 
                                </p:column>                                                                 
                                </p:dataTable>                              
                        </div>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your concrete problem. Are you saying that `#{userPreferences.availableQuestions}` didn't contain the updated data while in bean action method?

Comment: I mean to say how can i get the values of this dynamic list which are selected.

Comment: Just set `value="#{bean.value}"` and it'll just end up as `value` property of `#{bean}` the usual way. I have a hard time in understanding your actual problem with that as you appear to already have that part right elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Model has a boolean property in `Category` entity just do something like this (as said by @BalusC):

`<p:selectOneRadio id ="userChoice" value="#{tCategoryList.categoryBooleanValue}"  />`

If not you will have to create a new `CategoryWithAnswer` class in your presentation layer with a property to store the each user selection.
You could extend your Category Model class. And you will have to repopulate the list of categories for every element of `userPreferences.availableQuestions` list.

In summary you have to have some property bean in your Model to store the user answers. Usually this property exists in the Model
as part of the persistent entity bean.